# chrome.tabs.executeScript doesn't work in chrome.tabs.create callback

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: "about:blank"
}, function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        code: "window.setTimeout(function() {document.write(\"123\")},5000);"
    })
});
```

I'm writing a simple chrome plugin and want to open a new tab that only contains "123". I'm already using setTimeout to ensure that the code runs after loading, but "123" won't be written. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `document.write`..? When a document has finished loading, calling this method will replace the current document with whatever you put in the method call, in your case "123".

Comment: It's an empty document based on about:blank. I just want to display some information in a new tab. Document.write() works perfectly on about:blank in Chrome console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot run any content scripts on `about:blank` ([bug 55084](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=55084), [bug 76429](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=76429)).

If you want to display information in a new tab, either use a `data:`-URL,

```
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: "data:text/html,<script>" + 
         "window.setTimeout(function() {document.write(\"123\")},5000);" +
         "</script>"
});
```

or a page within your Chrome extension (note: [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) cannot be used to run content scripts on `chrome-extension:`-URLs either):

```
chrome.tabs.create({
    // TODO: Create a file called view.html that renders the result
    url: chrome.runtime.getURL("view.html")
});
```

`view.html` is subject to the [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html), so if you want to use scripts, it must be put in a separate file:

```html
<!-- view.html -->
<script src="view.js"></script>
```

```js
// view.js
window.setTimeout(function() {document.write("123")},5000);
```

Comment: Great Answer, thank you! I rather use data: since what is displayed will be decided at runtime.

Comment: @Aich You can also pass strings to the extension page as a query string or location fragment, i.e. `chrome.runtime.getURL("view.html") + '?123'` and in `view.js`, `document.write(location.search.slice(1));`